# How to remove Excel filters using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm using xlwings (0.21.4) to update a spreadsheet with data from external sources. The updates work fine unless any of the sheets contain filters. I'm looking for a way to disable filters within individual sheets within the workbook. I've seen other posts similar to this where the recommended solution is to set workbook.sheet.api.AutoFilterMode to False or use workbook.sheet.api.ShowAllData. However, neither of those are present within the api. The only elements that are available are 'after', 'any', 'before', 'beginning', 'beginswith', 'contains', 'doesnotbeginwith', 'doesnotcontain', 'doesnotendwith', 'end', 'endswith', 'first', 'help', 'isin', 'isnotin', 'isrunning', 'last', 'middle', 'next', 'previous', and 'relaunchmode'. What am I missing?

Comment: Please share your relevant lines of code and what you are trying exactly.

Comment: I just gave it a try and opening a workbook which has filters on with `wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')` and turning filters off with `wb.sheets[0].api.AutoFilterMode = False` works just fine with `xlwings` installed through `pip` in a fresh virtual environment. You probably have a typo in the code you're not sharing.

Comment: I don't believe it's a typo. I was able to set the AutoFilterMode to False, but it had no discernible effect on the spreadsheet. Additionally, I was unable to use the ShowAllData command. I've pasted the code below.

Comment: import xlwings as xw, xlapp = xw.App(add_book=False), wb = xlapp.books.open('test.xlsx'), wb.sheets[0].api.AutoFilterMode = False, wb.save(), xlapp.quit()